# $a,b,n \in \mathbb Z$. Find the smallest value of $n$ such that $b\mod n = a$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let $a,b,n \in \mathbb Z$. Find the smallest value of $n$ such that $b\mod n = a$ where $a,b$ are known values and $b > a$.

What's the most efficient way to solve such a problem? The naive approach would be choose values of $n$ and increment up until the smallest $n$ is found.

Comment: How would it work for $a=4, b=6$?

Comment: @Arthur That case doesn't work I suppose.

Comment: How is your $\bmod$ defined?

Comment: @mvw $\frac{b}{n}$ gives remainder $a$

Comment: Does it allow negative $n$?

Comment: @mvw all positive numbers

Answer (score 0):

"$b\ mod\ n\ =a$" means $\ b\equiv a\mod n\ $ , so we have $\ n|b-a\ $, thus the smallest positive value of $\ n\ $ is just the smallest prime factor of $\ b-a\ $, if we assume $n>1$. If $\ b-a=1\ $, the only solution is $n=1$, if we allow it.

In the case $n$ must be greater than $a$ :

If there is a divisor of $\ b-a\ $ which is greater than $a$, then the smallest of the divisors greater than $a$ is the optimal solution, but in this case, we do not always have a solution at all. For example $b=19$ , $a=16$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Peter. As an example, let $b=277,a=5$. Then $b-a=272$ with smallest prime factor of 2, but 2 doesn't satisfy the equation. $8$ is the smallest value of $n$ in this case. Am I misunderstanding your answer?

Comment: @WHY I edited the answer